# Arranging the checkbox in checkboxtableviewer horizontally in eclipse e4

Tags: java, eclipse, jface, e4

I am using eclipse e4 application. I am displaying a checkboxtableviewer in a Part. Now the checkbox are arranged vertically like the following pattern below.

> checkbox MIN
>
> checkbox MAX
>
> checkbox AVG
>
> checkbox COUNT

the following is the code snippet I have used.

```
public class StatisticsPart {

private CheckboxTableViewer tableViewer;
public Object[] statisticsSelected;

@Inject
public StatisticsPart() {
    //TODO Your code here
}

@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct(Composite parent) {
     tableViewer = new CheckboxTableViewer(parent, SWT.BORDER|SWT.HORIZONTAL);
     tableViewer.add("MIN");
     tableViewer.add("MAX");
     tableViewer.add("AVG");
     tableViewer.add("COUNT");
     tableViewer.getTable().setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));
     tableViewer.addCheckStateListener(new ICheckStateListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void checkStateChanged(CheckStateChangedEvent event) {
            statisticsSelected =  tableViewer.getCheckedElements();
        }
    });

}
}
```

I want to display the checkbox name horizontally and all the corresponding checkboxes below it like the following pattern.

> MIN        MAX        AVG        COUNT
>
> checkbox   checkbox   checkbox    checkbox

Can anyone please help how to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `CheckboxTableViewer` only supports one check box per table row.

Comment: is there any other suggestions to make it look like the below arrangement that I have mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CheckboxTableViewer` only supports one check box per row.

You could use a normal `TableViewer` and define four columns.

Use a `ColumnLabelProvider` for each column and override the `getImage` method to provide a checked or unchecked image.

You can change the value by using a `CheckboxCellEditor` in the editing support for the column.

Comment: for adding the checked/unchecked images I am using `private static final Image UNCHECKED = Activator.getImageDescriptor("icons/unchecked.gif").createImage();` But what is the package that i should import for the `Activator`.?